# Extract all line from a file that contains two strings in any position

Tags: awk, sed, grep

I have a .txt file with contents similar to this:

- 100 150 180 200 300 400
- 100 200 250 350 380 400
- 100 160 170 400 450 500
- 100 120 140 160 180 200
- 100 120 140 160 180 300

I want to grab all the lines, starting from a specific column (like 2, 3 or any other) that contains '100' and '200' in any postion and then output it to another separate txt file. How can I do that? In the example above, the correct print should be:

- 100 150 180 200 300 400
- 100 200 250 350 380 400
- 100 120 140 160 180 200

I have tried using sublime's "Find All" feature and then use the right arrow to the end of the line to highlight them, but unfortunately some lines are much longer than the others so it doesn't work.

Comment: @JeffSchaller With the recent edit, no longer a duplicate.

Comment: close-vote retracted; thanks @Kusalananda

Comment: None of your sample lines has `100` and `200` in fields from 3 on, so ir's impossible to get at your desired output.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ grep 100 <file | grep 200 >newfile
$ cat newfile
100 150 180 200 300 400
100 200 250 350 380 400
100 120 140 160 180 200
```

The first `grep` extracts all lines from the original file that contains the string `100`.  The second `grep` extracts all lines *from that result* that contains the string `200`.

Note that this would also extract lines that contained strings like `1100` and `1200` since these contains the wanted strings as substrings.  To avoid that, use `grep` with its `-w` option (if available).

---

To test only from a specific column onwards, use a short `awk` program:

```
$ awk -v col=1 '{ delete c; for (i=col; i<=NF; ++i) ++c[$i]; if (c[100] > 0 && c[200] > 0) print }' <file >newfile
$ cat newfile
100 150 180 200 300 400
100 200 250 350 380 400
100 120 140 160 180 200
```

This `awk` program takes a the value of the `col` variable from the command line (here the value is 1).  It then goes through each input line from column `col` onwards, counting how many times each value occurs.  If the values `100` and `200` occurs more than zero times, the line is printed.

The program, with nicer layout:

```
{
    delete c

    for (i=col; i<=NF; ++i)
        ++c[$i]

    if (c[100] > 0 && c[200] > 0)
        print
}
```

This program also lends itself to extracting lines with *specific* number of matches of certain items.

Comment: Thanks, @Kusalananda. Is there a way to start the search from an specific column?

Comment: @Hector Please update the question to make it complete. I'm avoiding answering followup questions in comments, and if you keep changing the question, it runs the risk of being closed as "unclear".

Comment: It's done. Sorry for that, Kusalananda.

Comment: @Hector See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks so much, @Kusalananda! Your answer is absolutely complete!

Comment: Hey, @Jusalananda. I was trying your code for number with 3 or more digits and the command couldn't find them properly. Is there anything I have to change?

Comment: @Hector What do you mean by "three or more digits"?

Comment: Ops, I mean less than 3 digits, like 2 3 4 or 02 10 and 27.

Comment: @Hector I still don't know what you are trying to do with numbers that have less than three digits.

Comment: Something like
- 13 15 17 40 53 57
- 05 17 33 39 42 49
- 05 14 33 36 43 44
- 17 19 28 45 48 56
- 07 14 15 29 38 50

Comment: Now it makes sense, @Kusalananda

Comment: @Hector You could just adjust the numbers `100` and `200` in the code. I'm not sure what you want to de.

Comment: @Kusalanda, yes, I've tried it but it doesn't work. The only way (very nasty way btw) was it: awk -f ' ' '{ if((($3 == 02) || ($4 == 02) || ($5 == 02) || ($6 == 02) || ($7 == 02) || ($8 == 02)) && (($3 == 10) || ($4 == 10) || ($5 == 10) || ($6 == 10) || ($7 == 10) || ($8 == 10))) { print } }' file

Comment: @Hector If you want to make a difference between `2` and `02` then use `"02"` in the test: `c["02"] > 0`.

Comment: Amazing, that worked exactly how I need! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that there won't be false positives, try also

```
awk '{TMP = $0; sub ($1 FS $2, "")} /100/ && /200/ {print TMP} ' file
```